# Difficulty in applying a function over a sequence, when the function doesnt take the sequence as an argument

Tags: r

Difficulty in applying a function over a sequence, when the function doesn’t take the sequence as an argument and when the function uses values returned from the function itself at the previous value of the sequence.

I have the following problem. In my main method function `mainn`, I will first initialise `fa`, `mu.a`, `mu.b`, `sigma`, which will then be used as arguments in the `step2` function. (Please note that I am pretty sure that my `px.q4` and `step2` are working correctly/properly in the sense that `px.q4` returns a value and `step2` returns 3 values)

This is where my question enters. 
I would like to perform apply `step2` over a sequence, and every time it applies over the sequence (except for the first iteration), the `step2` function will use **NOT the initial values** but the values of `fa.iter`, `mu.a.iter`, `mu.b.iter` from the previous `step2`. Can this be done in R? Or do I have to use a for-loop for this sort of question

I was able to do this using a for-loop. However, I want to learn more about R. Is there a (more efficient) particular command that I can use to get around the problem?

```
#this function returns a value    
px.q4 <- function(fa, mu.a, mu.b,sigma)
{   
  v <- fa + mu.a + mu.b * sigma
  v
}

#this function returns 3 values, fa.iter, mu.a.iter, and mu.b.iter
#for completeness I include the full code of what i am trying to do. 
#But all you need to know is that the function step2 returns 3 values .
step2 <- function(fa, mu.a, mu.b)
{

  #set prev = iter values // this also allow set initial values = prev in 
  #the 1st iteration
  mu.a.prev <- mu.a.iter
  mu.b.prev <- mu.b.iter
  fa.prev <- fa.iter

  #draw a trail point x.trail from propsal distribution ~ N(x_i-1,0.1)
  mu.a.trail <- rnorm(1, mu.a.prev, 0.1)
  mu.b.trail <- rnorm(1, mu.b.prev, 0.1)
  fa.trail <- rnorm(1, fa.prev, 0.1)
  while(fa.trail < 0 || fa.trail > 1)         
  {
    fa.trail <- rnorm(1, fa.prev, sigma)
  }
  #if p(x_trail) >= p(x_i-1) set x_i = x_trail
  a <- px.q4(fa.trail, mu.a.trail, mu.b.trail, sigma) 
  b <- px.q4(fa.prev ,mu.a.prev , mu.b.prev,sigma)
  if(a >= b)
  {
    mu.a.iter <- mu.a.trail
    mu.b.iter <- mu.b.trail
    fa.iter <- fa.trail
  }else{
    r <- runif(1,min = 0, max = 1)
    if(r < a/b){
      mu.a.iter <- mu.a.trail
      mu.b.iter <- mu.b.trail
      fa.iter <- fa.trail
    }else{
      mu.a.iter <- mu.a.prev
      mu.b.iter <- mu.b.prev
      fa.iter <- fa.prev
    }
  }

  res <-  list(mu.a.iter,  mu.b.iter,  fa.iter)
  res
}
#main body

mainn <- function(n,fa,mu.a,mu.b)
{
  sigma <- 0.3
  mu.a.init <- mu.a               #initial values 
  mu.b.init <- mu.b
  fa.init <- fa           #(must be between 0 and 1)

  #set initial values = iter values (for entering for loop)
  mu.a.iter <- mu.a.init
  mu.b.iter <- mu.b.init
  fa.iter <- fa.init

  #where to the logical flaw comes in and how can I overcome it
    y <- sapply(n,FUN = step2)

}
```

Comment: Can you make this example any simpler? Get rid of all the specifics of your analysis and just leave the essence of your problem. I feel like it could be shown in about five lines of R. As it stands, 90% of the people on here aren't going to bother.

Comment: will simplify this later on. Sorry

Comment: As a general rule. You CANNOT EVER vectorise or parallelise a function that takes it's own result as input.

Comment: @StephenHenderson I agree, with the exception of recursive functions (which is not what the OP wants).  PS watch those apostrophes!:-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Reduce` to apply a function recursively over a list: 
for instance,

```
Reduce(`+`, 1:10, accumulate=TRUE)
```

is equivalent to `cumsum(1:10)`.

In your case, you are not applying the function over a list,
but just iterating it: you can still use `Reduce`, if you ignore the second argument.

```
# It is easier if your function takes a vector and returns a vector.
# The second argument is ignored.
step2 <- function(x, u) cumsum(x) + rnorm(length(x))
r <- Reduce(step2, 1:100, init=c(0,0,0), accumulate = TRUE)
```

But there is nothing wrong in using a loop: it should not be significantly slower, unless your function is very fast.